# I cant send specified messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have this issue I can't send messages to specific channels I was able tgo send messages with this Code:

```js
let Channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get("749002989255131227");
Channel.send("Hello!")
```

But I when I try to send it didnt worked error:

```
(node:13580) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Channel.send is not a function
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\alier\Desktop\hesapver\index.js:322:30)
    at Client.emit (events.js:321:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\alier\Desktop\hesapver\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\alier\Desktop\hesapver\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\alier\Desktop\hesapver\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\alier\Desktop\hesapver\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\alier\Desktop\hesapver\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\alier\Desktop\hesapver\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:321:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\alier\Desktop\hesapver\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:797:20)
```

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: Try logging `Channel` and seeing what it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **'discord.js' v12** try console.log(Channel) and see what it is,

else try

let messageChannel = bot.guilds.channels.get('ID')

messageChannel.send('message')

Comment: Im using discord.js v12 and it is showing channel details.

Comment: try to make what i say

Comment: if you try what i say, the bot variable is for me, your can be client, app, whatever